SwiftUI List with images from API is lagging
I'm using SwiftUI to build a list with images from an API. There's some lagging while the image is being downloaded. I can understand that the issue comes from the CatRowView, because when I replace it with a Image(systemName: it doesn't lag, but AsyncImage is async, so I don't know why this happens.
final class CatsGridViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let apiService: APIService
    private (set) var page = 0
    @Published var catsArray: [Cat] = []

    var isLoading = false
    
    init(apiService: APIService = APIService()) {
        self.apiService = apiService
    }

    func isLastCat(id: String) -> Bool {
        return catsArray.last?.id == id
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func fetchCats() async {
        if !isLoading {
            isLoading = true
            let array = await apiService.fetchImages(.thumb, page: page, limit: 25)
            catsArray.append(contentsOf: array)
            page += 1
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
}

struct CatGridView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = CatsGridViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(viewModel.catsArray) { cat in
                        VStack {
                            CatRowView(cat: cat)
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                            }.onAppear {
                                if viewModel.isLastCat(id: cat.id) {
                                    Task {
                                        await viewModel.fetchCats()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .task {
                await viewModel.fetchCats()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Cats: \(viewModel.page)")
        }
    }
}

struct CatRowView: View {
    
    var cat: Cat
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: cat.url)!) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        }
    }
}

The code above is not enough to reproduce the error, if possible clone or download the project to visually understand what I'm saying about the delay of the images with the compiled project. The link on Github is:
https://github.com/brunosilva808/Sword

The code you show here is not the code that gives you the lag is it?
You don't show that in your real code you also have attached to the CatView(cat: cat)
a .onAppear {...} where you call await viewModel.fetchCats()
again and again for each entry in the ForEach. No wonder why you get some lagging.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I updated the code. I call it when I reach the last item on the forEach. Only the last one.

I'm not sure I understand what kind of lag you're referring to, but your AsyncImage is built in a way that it changes size depending on its phase. while downloading the image, you're showing a small ProgressView, and when the download is complete the whole stack needs to resize itself.  try moving the fixed frame modifier from successful image phase and move it to the whole AsyncImage

@BrunoFulberWide found an article that also shows the issue with AsyncImage https://medium.com/@alex_persian/the-case-against-asyncimage-22a073044746

I downloaded your project and made changes to two files: ContentView and Cat
Sword/Model/Cat:
Added Identifiable protocol
struct Cat: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable

Sword/View/ContenView
Added a simple cache using NSCache. This allows images that have already been downloaded to be stored in memory, avoiding repeated downloading and rendering when scrolling through the list.
import SwiftUI

// Global cache to store images that have been downloaded
class ImageCache {
    static let shared = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
}

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let apiService: APIService
    private var page = 0
    @Published var catsArray: [Cat] = []
    @Published var searchTerm = ""
    
    var filteredCatsArray: [Cat] {
        // Filters the cats array based on the search term if it's not empty
        guard !searchTerm.isEmpty else { return catsArray }
        return catsArray.filter { $0.breedName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm) }
    }
    
    // Checks if the current cat is the last one in the list
    func isLastCat(id: String) -> Bool {
        return catsArray.last?.id == id
    }
    
    init(apiService: APIService = APIService()) {
        self.apiService = apiService
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func fetchCats() async {
        // Fetches a new batch of cat images from the API and appends them to the array
        catsArray.append(contentsOf: await apiService.fetchImages(.thumb, page: page, limit: 25))
        page += 1
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel() // Observes changes in the ViewModel
    private let columns = [ GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100)) ] // Adaptive grid layout
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                // LazyVGrid ensures that only visible items are loaded, improving scroll performance
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.filteredCatsArray, id: \.id) { cat in
                        VStack {
                            // Custom view that handles loading images from cache or downloading them
                            CatImageView(url: cat.url)
                            Text(cat.breedName) // Displays the breed name
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            // When the last cat in the list appears, fetch more data
                            if viewModel.isLastCat(id: cat.id) {
                                Task {
                                    await viewModel.fetchCats()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Cats") // Title of the navigation bar
            .onAppear {
                // Fetches the initial batch of cats when the view appears
                Task {
                    await viewModel.fetchCats()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// View to handle loading the image either from cache or by downloading it
struct CatImageView: View {
    let url: String
    
    var body: some View {
        // Checks if the image is already in the cache
        if let cachedImage = ImageCache.shared.object(forKey: url as NSString) {
            // If cached, show the cached image
            Image(uiImage: cachedImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .clipped()
        } else {
            // Otherwise, use AsyncImage to download the image
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: url)) { phase in
                if let image = phase.image {
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .clipped()
                        .onAppear {
                            // Once downloaded, store the image in the cache
                            ImageCache.shared.setObject(image.asUIImage(), forKey: url as NSString)
                        }
                } else if phase.error != nil {
                    // Show a red placeholder if there was an error
                    Color.red.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                } else {
                    // Show a progress view while the image is loading
                    ProgressView().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Helper function to convert a SwiftUI Image to a UIImage for caching
extension Image {
    func asUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: view!.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}

This modifications should make the scrolling smoother and reduce the need to re-download images when scrolling back up.
Let me know how it performs!

I see that you removed the CatView and moved it to the ContentView, but that alone doesn't fix the performance issue. I think the problem is a bit deeper like we can see in this article https://medium.com/@alex_persian/the-case-against-asyncimage-22a073044746

I think you must have gotten confused with the names. I didn't remove CatView and move it to ContentView. The View inside ContentView is CatImageView (this helps about image caching). CatView remains in the same place. I only changed 2 files: Cat and ContentView. In the case of ContentView I did 2 solution approaches.

I forked your project and I made a PR. You can see what was changed. About the article you shared is great. My approach was try to follow the second approach the author of the article mentioned: CachedAsyncImage.

It's not an optimal solution but I think it's the max we can do at this point with SwiftUI

.task replaces @StateObject so try removing that class. The basics are return cats as a result from your async func. Put this async func in a struct that is not main actor, eg CatsController which usually is an EnvironmentKey. Call it from .task and set the result on an @State.
Use task(id:page) for pages.

Why would this affect the behavior?

Because they put the async func in that object they had to mark it main actor which made it lag

How much do you suspect that lag to be? I suspect almost nothing.

Main thread blocked during every download so depends how big each image batch is and how many batches but I’d suspect serious lag while it’s downloading each batch of 25 images.

But the main thread isn't necessarily blocked. The await apiService.fetchImages is a suspension point. Unless they somehow managed to run the actual download on the main thread (which is essentially not possible with the default Apple APIs at least), there's very little running on it. I don't think there's evidence that task in this case would meaningfully make a change, but I guess we'll see what the OP says.

Can u share some code? First call is inside task but next calls are on a different task, so a bit of code would help. Wanna mark this correct if it works

you need to remove @MainActor from the async func otherwise it won't run on a background thread. Also need to move isLoading out of the class and into an @State in the View model struct.

I don't see any difference in behaviour. I can remove @MainActor but have to use MainActor.run so it's not very different.

Remove that too

@malhal Then how would I update the UI without a call to the main thread? Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed

that's why I also said move isLoading out of the class and into an @State in the View model struct but I forgot to mention you should also move the cats array too. Return it from your async func.

Sorry mate, but that doesn't explain how to run it on the main thread. Thanks anyway

.task already runs on main thread, no explanation is needed
